# Semantic UI Regex parser does not seem to work correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, semantic-ui

In my credit card checkout form I have the following:

```
    $('#checkout-info')
        .form({
            on     : 'blur',
            fields : {
                    id_cc_num : {   identifier: 'id_cc_num',
                                    optional: true,
                                    rules: []},
                    id_cc_CVC : {   identifier: 'id_cc_CVC',
                                    optional: true,
                                    rules: [{   type: 'regExp[/\d{3,4}/]',
                                                prompt: 'CVC must be three or four digits'}]},
                    id_cc_month : { identifier: 'id_cc_month',
                                    optional: true,
                                    rules: [{   type: 'integer[1..12]',
                                                prompt: 'MM must be a two-digit month designator - 01 thru 12'}]},
                    id_cc_year : {  identifier: 'id_cc_year',
                                    optional: true,
                                    rules: [{   type: 'integer[2016..2036]',
                                                prompt: 'Year must be at least 2016'}]},
            inline : 'true'
        });
```

All validation shown works correctly except the regExp validation.  The regex /\d{3,4}/ passes the regex test in www.regexr.com, but it will not pass the Semantic regExp test.  If the regExp on the CVC field is replaced with the following, then it works, but I prefer the brevity of the regex:

```
rules: [{   type: 'minLength[3]',
            prompt: 'CVC must be three or four digits'},
        {   type: 'maxLength[4]',
            prompt: 'CVC must be three or four digits'}]},
```

Comment: regExp is the Semantic UI keyword for validating regex's, so in the context of Semantic UI, it is semantically correct:  http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#validation-rules

Comment: Yes, I had already tried it, also, with the leading ^ and trailing $, without success.  Seems like it must be a small glitch in the library.

Comment: I was just searching on SO and saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27346648/4227915) ... but, if the documentation says this way is correct, then it is.  ':)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the `regExp` expression being part of a string, you will need escape the backslash by using a double backslash `\\`, along with the leading `^` and `$` to ignore matching patterns found in larger numbers. The resulting pattern will be:

```
'regExp[/^\\d{3,4}$/]'
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkout-info').form({
    on: 'blur',
    fields: {
      id_cc_CVC: {
        identifier: 'id_cc_CVC',
        optional: true,
        rules: [{
          type: 'regExp[/^\\d{3,4}$/]',
          prompt: 'CVC must be three or four digits'
        }]
      },
    },
    inline: 'true'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ui container">
  <form class="ui form" id="checkout-info">
    <div class="field">
      <label for="id_cc_CVC">CVC</label>
      <input type="text" id="id_cc_CVC" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="ui button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```